# AJAX form wont post

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, post

Hi everyone I am trying to submit a form without the page reloading, a seemingly straightforward thing with AJAX, but I can't seem to get any changes on my database.  I have an alert set in my javascript to run if the AJAX was successful, and it seems to trigger every time, so I think the variables are, indeed, getting sent out of the AJAX, but when I get to join.php, I don't think it remembers, and therefore doesn't process correctly.

First of all, here is the relevant script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //----SUBMIT---//
    $(".submit").click(function () {
        // validate and process form here  

        $('.error').hide();
        var studentEmail = $("input#studentEmail").val();
        if (studentEmail == "") {

            $("label#studentEmail_error").show();
            $("input#studentEmail").focus();
            return false;
        }

        var studentPassword = $("#studentPassword").val();
        var parentEmail = $("#parentEmail").val();
        var parentPassword = $("#parentPassword").val();
        var studentFirstName = $("#studentFirstName").val();
        var studentLastName = $("#studentLastName").val();
        var studentPhone = $("#studentPhone").val();
        var parentFirstName = $("#parentFirstName").val();
        var parentLastName = $("#parentLastName").val();
        var parentPhone = $("#parentPhone").val();


        var dataString = 'studentEmail=' + studentEmail 
                         + '&studentPassword=' + studentPassword 
                         + '&parentEmail=' + parentEmail 
                         + '&parentPassword=' + parentPassword 
                         + '&studentFirstName=' + studentFirstName 
                         + '&studentLastName=' + studentLastName 
                         + '&studentPhone=' + studentPhone 
                         + '&parentFirstName=' + parentFirstName 
                         + '&parentLastName=' + parentLastName 
                         + '&parentPhone=' + parentPhone;

        alert(dataString);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "join.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Then join.php

```
if($_POST) {
    $studentEmail=$_POST['studentEmail'];
    $studentPassword=$_POST['studentPassword'];
    $parentEmail=$_POST['parentEmail'];
    $parentPassword=$_POST['parentPassword'];
    $studentFirstName=$_POST['studentFirstName'];
    $studentLastName=$_POST['studentLastName'];
    $studentPhone=$_POST['studentPhone'];
    $parentFirstName=$_POST['parentFirstName'];
    $parentLastName=$_POST['parentLastName'];
    $parentPhone=$_POST['parentPhone'];

    //create database connection
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX"); 
        //in case database connection fails
        if(!$connection) {
            die("Database connection failed: ".mysql_error());
        }

        else{

        //select database to use
        $db_select = mysql_select_db("XXXX",$connection); 
            //in case database selection fails
            if (!$db_select) { 
                die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
            } 

            else {

            //make sql query
              $sql = "INSERT INTO clients (`studentEmail`, 
                                                   `studentPassword`, 
                                                   `parentEmail`, 
                                                   `parentPassword`,
                                                   `studentFirstName`, 
                                                   `studentLastName`, 
                                                   `studentPhone`, 
                                                   `parentFirstName`, 
                                                   `parentLastName`, 
                                                   `parentPhone`)
                    VALUES ('".$studentEmail."', 
                            '".$studentPassword"', 
                            '".$parentEmail."', 
                            '".$parentPassword."', 
                            '".$studentFirstName."', 
                            '".$studentLastName."', 
                            '".$studentPhone."', 
                            '".$parentFirstName."', 
                            '".$parentLastName."', 
                            '".$parentPhone."')";

                //set results to variables
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                //in case query fails
                if (!$result) { 
                    die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); 
                } 
            }
        }

}

else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but a simple way to get form data in jQuery is to use `$('yourForm').serialize()`. Thought I'd pass the tip along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the `$.post()` call into this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "join.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {
      alert ("Success: "+ data);
    }
});
```

And, at the beginning of PHP code, place this:

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

This way, the alert message will display the data received from PHP.

### UPDATE:

Since I see nobody here is seeing the hugest security risk with that code, I add it here:

Be very sure that you pass every single string from post through `mysql_real_escape_string()` before adding it inside the query!

What if anybody posts this as his email address??:

```
'); DROP TABLE clients; --
```

### UPDATE:

I double-checked documentation of `jQuery.ajax()` and `jQuery.post()`. While `.post()` is just a shortcut for `.ajax()`, their syntax is different:

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
jQuery.ajax( settings )
```

(updated code above too).

### UPDATE:

Try this code, that should work "out of the box":

The JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".submit").click(function() {  

        $('.error').hide();  
        var studentEmail = $("input#studentEmail").val();  
        if (studentEmail == "") {  
            $("label#studentEmail_error").show();  
            $("input#studentEmail").focus();  
            return false;  
        }

        var dataString = {
            studentEmail : studentEmail,
            studentPassword : $("#studentPassword").val(),
            parentEmail : $("#parentEmail").val(),
            parentPassword : $("#parentPassword").val(),
            studentFirstName : $("#studentFirstName").val(),
            studentLastName : $("#studentLastName").val(),
            studentPhone : $("#studentPhone").val(),
            parentFirstName : $("#parentFirstName").val(),
            parentLastName : $("#parentLastName").val(),
            parentPhone : $("#parentPhone").val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "join.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                alert ("success: "+ data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

The PHP code

```
var_dump($_POST);
echo "\n\n"; // Some white space here

if($_POST) {
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","XXXX","XXXX"); 
    if(!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: ". mysql_error());
    }
    if (!mysql_select_db("XXXX",$connection)) { 
        die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error()); 
    }

    // Read data from POST
    $studentEmail       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentEmail']);
    $studentPassword    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentPassword']);
    $parentEmail        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parentEmail']);
    $parentPassword     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parentPassword']);
    $studentFirstName   = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentFirstName']);
    $studentLastName    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentLastName']);
    $studentPhone       = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['studentPhone']);
    $parentFirstName    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parentFirstName']);
    $parentLastName     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parentLastName']);
    $parentPhone        = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['parentPhone']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO clients ".
        "(`studentEmail`, `studentPassword`, `parentEmail`, `parentPassword`, ".
        "`studentFirstName`, `studentLastName`, `studentPhone`, `parentFirstName`, ".
        "`parentLastName`, `parentPhone`) ".
        " VALUES ('$studentEmail', '$studentPassword', '$parentEmail', ".
        "'$parentPassword', '$studentFirstName', '$studentLastName', ".
        "'$studentPhone', '$parentFirstName', '$parentLastName', '$parentPhone')";

    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if ($result) { 
        echo "Database query successful!";
    }
    else {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That one is not just a security hole, but can lead to random problems wherever an apostrophe is submitted into a form field.. that's why it's absolutely mandatory to escape values. Anyways, did you try adding that debugging code, as I suggested?

Comment: I'm sorry for the slow response.  Stackoverflow wasn't letting me log on for some reason.  Anyway, that worked!  Thank you so much for your help, this problem had been driving me nuts for days.  I also appreciate the extra security information.  I'm still not quite sure what I was doing wrong, could you explain it again?

Comment: I guess that it was the mysql query failing for some reason (missing quotes would be a valid reason!) so the record won't get stored. Anyways, now it's also easier to debug since all the echoed data from the php script is returned to the JavaScript, so you can show it in an alert / inside a div somewhere / ...
Now, the homework: try using something like a for loop in order to remove all these repetitions in the central part of the php script..

Answer (score 0):

You have a mysql error, dont have a quotes:

**Corrected:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clients (`studentEmail`, `studentPassword`, `parentEmail`, `parentPassword`, `studentFirstName`, `studentLastName`, `studentPhone`, `parentFirstName`, `parentLastName`, `parentPhone`)
                        VALUES ('".$studentEmail."', '".$studentPassword"', '".$parentEmail."', '".$parentPassword."', '".$studentFirstName."', '".$studentLastName."', '".$studentPhone."', '".$parentFirstName."', '".$parentLastName."', '".$parentPhone."')";
```

Comment: Yeah, good point.. It was more likely a server-side-related problem than a client-side one..

Comment: By the way, I hope you know how to sanitize strings before using them in a query..

Comment: I had done this at some point a while back, but it wasn't the problem.  I have updated it up top with this new sql

Comment: My sql worked in the mysql workbench, so I really think it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the script with dummy values to make sure it working correctly.

You can remove the quotes ("")from the sql and replace with '$variable' which converts the whole query to a string.

Is the join.php in the same directory?

Are you throwing a cross domain error in your developer tools? If so you may have to use the jQuery workaround.

Comment: yeah, I tried removing the quotes and putting in actual values, but it still wasn't passing them through.  Also, it is in the same directory.  I'm not sure what you man about your last question.

Comment: ajax sometimes has trouble posting to file on the same server and can throw up an exception 101 error. If you have a developer tool like firebug or the inbuilt on within chrome. You can watch what happens on the js side when you trigger the function. It will log the error. jQuery has a work around if this is the problem. (However I am not familar with it.)

Answer (score 0):

Your alert should fire whether or not the actual PHP code is executed- as long as it receives a response.

I would try to put an 'echo "TEST"' statement before your if($_POST) statement to debug. Continue messing with this method until you figure out where exactly your code is failing. If it still isn't executing the POST, check the file path for join.php and ensure it is in the same directory.

Also, are you trying to do this locally or is it hosted on a web server?

Another note, you should use encodeURI(..) on user input prior to posting, as good practice.

Here is a refactor for the way you generate the data string, consider:

```
//create an object
var dataObj = {};

//get inputs from form with id = formID
//for each input, add a property matching the input id to the dataObj and store the value of the field as the value for that property.
$("#formID :input").each( function (this) {

    var id = this.attr(id); //might be a bit off
    var val = this.val();   //same here

    dataObj[id] = encodeURI(val);

});
```

Syntax might be a bit off, haven't done this in awhile.

Comment: Yeah, also iterating stuff wouldn't be bad to clean up that code a bit.. code should be something like: `$('#formID').find('input,select,textarea').each(function(){ var id=$(this).attr('id'); var val=$(this).val(); dataObj[id] = val; })` (`encodeURI()` is applied automatically)

Comment: Even better, you can just use jQuery's Serialize function. http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I'm not quite sure where to put the alert exactly because the user never sees join.php, the data is just processed through there.  How can i see what variables are there at that point if I have nowhere to echo it?

Comment: also, this is hosted on a webserver, not locally